# Create/authenticate a connector on a button click?

Tags: authentication, connector, powerapps, power-automate

I added a Trello (*for example*) connector and built a PowerApp on top of it. The problem is, we need to share/publish the app to multiple clients now, and obviously, they do not want to share their Trello (*for example*) login credentials.

I tried to do a research on this, but, didn't find a good solution. Only possibility which I could think about is adding Trello (*for example*) as a Custom Connector. But, then, why would I use PowerApps? I could have achieved it in my ASP.Net-MVC website itself.

How can I add a Trello (*for example*) authentication or a login screen in PowerApps? Is it possible to do this in first place? Am I missing something in PowerApps where I could achieve it easily?

Thanks in advance!